# Group objects of a stream into a Map

Tags: java, set, java-stream

Ive got a Stream of Cars with a certain hp amount and a set of hp intervalls.
Now I need to store the hp intervall with all the cars inside a Map.

```
Map<hpIntervall, Set<car>>
```

The `HPIntervall` class got a `fromHP` and a `toHP` int, so I can get them with `.getTo()` and `.getFrom()`.

I allready tried the `stream.collect(Collectors.groupBy())` but I think I missunderstand the syntax at all. Can someone give me an approach?

```
 public static Map<HPIntervall, Set<Car>> groupCarsByHP(Stream<Car> cars,
            Set<HPIntervall> hpIntervalls) {

        return cars.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> {
                    for (HPIntervall hpInt : hpintervalls) {
                        if (c.getHP() >= ic.fromHP() && c.getHP() <= ic.toHP()) {
                            return hpInt;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }, Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code that you tried?

Comment: How should `hpIntervall` be computed?

Comment: Ive got a class  hpIntervall and then a set of this class.

Comment: Something that catches the eye right away are the lower case class names. This is close to a capital sin when working in a team. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Then what are `fromHP` and `toHP`? Does `Car` have `hpIntervall` as a field?

Comment: What's `hpintervalls`?